# Is the following statement true ? If $L$ is a decidable language and $L' \subseteq \; L$, then $L'$ is also decidable ? Prove your answer is correct

Tags: computability

Is the following statement true ? If $L$ is a decidable language and $L' \subseteq \; L$, then $L'$ is also decidable ? Prove your answer is correct

I can't figure out this question. Any tips ?

Answer (score 2):

It isn't necessarily true. For a counterexample, take the language $L$ to consist of all strings in a nontrivial signature. This is easily seen to be decidable. But there are some languages $L'$ in the signature that are undecidable, such as the halting problem, and these have $L'\subset L$, making a counterexample.

A different argument shows that the phenomenon is actually pervasive: every infinite language has uncountably many sublanguages, but only countably many of them can be decidable. So every infinite language $L$ has an undecidable sublanguage $L'\subset L$.

Comment: What do you mean by "strings in a nontrivial signature" ?

Comment: The signature is the set of symbols used to make the strings --- you might call it the "alphabet" of the language. A string is a finite sequence of symbols. A language is a set of strings. Basically, my first counterexample is to let $L$ be everything. This is decidable, but there are undecidable $L'\subset L$.

Comment: This is an insignificant point, but even when the signature has only has one symbol there are still uncountably many languages.

Comment: @CarlMummert Yes, you are right! I added that in, thinking of $2^\omega$, but I don't need it, and so I edited it back out.